# Relocate my images at startup

Tags: jquery, css, image

I have, in several places in my css, entries such as:

```
button {
  background-image: url('../images/button.png');
}
```

I want a function in jQuery that will change all occurrences of `images/` in all `background-image` urls to something like:

```
button {
  background-image: url('../images/Customer/button.png');
}
```

I currently do it with this horrible piece of code but I suspect there is a much neater way using jQuery. Note that the actual location of the images is held in `sessionStorage`.

```
// Hacks all CSS styles that refer to the images folder.
for ( s = 0; s < document.styleSheets.length; s++ ) {
  var mysheet=document.styleSheets[s];
  var myrules=mysheet.cssRules? mysheet.cssRules: mysheet.rules;
  // Look for: background-image: url(images/button.png); 
  for (i=0; i < myrules.length; i++){
    var css = myrules[i].style.cssText;
    if(css.indexOf('images/') != -1 ){
      // Surgery on the cssText because the individual entries are read only.
      // Replace the css.
      myrules[i].style.cssText = css.replace("images/", sessionStorage.images);
      // That's the new style.

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this plugin with jQuery:

**jQuery.Rule** -- http://flesler-plugins.googlecode.com/files/jquery.rule-1.0.2-min.js

then do the following:

```
$(function(){

    var customer = 'Oscar';

    // Get all stylesheets
    $.rule().sheets.map(function(index, cssSheet){
            // Get all css rules from all the stylesheets
        $.each(cssSheet.cssRules, function(index, cssRule){
            // If cssRule is 'background-image' type
            if(cssRule.cssText.indexOf('background-image') != -1){
                // Prepare new cssRule adding the customer
                var newCssRule = cssRule.cssText.replace('/images/', '/images/' + customer + '/');
                // Add new cssRule to the correct stylesheet
                $.rule(newCssRule).appendTo('style');
            }
        });
    });

});
```

just to know, you can do more things with this, take a look at this link:

http://flesler.webs.com/jQuery.Rule/

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Looks like a good package. I don't just want `../Images/Customer/button.png`, I want **all** occurrences of `images/` in **all** `url`s in **all** `background-image` entries in **all** css to change to include the customer name.

Comment: One main one and about three others that are component specific. I expect more as the system develops.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need jQuery here.

Try introducing a new CSS definition for `button` and add it to the page. This will override your previous definition.

```
var style = document.createElement('style');
style.type = 'text/css';
style.innerHTML = 'button { background-image: url("../images/Customer/button.png"); }';
document.head.appendChild(style);
```

Or, adjust the inline CSS of the `button` elements:

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button'),
    i = 0;

for (; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].style.backgroundImage = 'url("../images/Customer/button.png")';
}
```