# Is it possible to set the cssText property of a cssRule

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to edit the cssText property of a cssRule. I've seen it done often:

- [Why does altering the height in cssText remove the background: none?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17353184/why-does-altering-the-height-in-csstext-remove-the-background-none)
- [Relocate my images at startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11886222/relocate-my-images-at-startup)

Usually its done using : cssText.replace( ... ).

It seems to work for everybody except me. Can someone please explain me why the following will not work :

```
    var cssText = document.styleSheets[1].cssRules[0].cssText;
    document.styleSheets[1].cssRules[0].cssText = cssText.replace( "red", "yellow" );
```

Fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/KbkFH/3/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You almost had it.  You were just missing the `style`

```
$( document ).ready(
function() {
    //.style was missing
    var cssText = document.styleSheets[1].cssRules[0].style.cssText;
    document.styleSheets[1].cssRules[0].style.cssText = cssText.replace( "red", "yellow" );
    }
);
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KbkFH/6/

NOTE: if the rule included a class name of `redesign` it would replace the class name to be `yellowesign` which might not be what you want.  Just be careful when using replace without parsing the styles or targetting a specific style.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your code is working as aspected.

> [**`CSSRule.cssText:`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSRule.cssText) cssText returns the actual text of the
>   style rule

Check this [**Using dynamic styling information**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Using_dynamic_styling_information?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/Using_dynamic_styling_information)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript DOM style

```js
  var div = document.querySelectorAll("div");
 
  div[0].style.cssText = "border: 5px solid yellow; padding: 10px"; 
  div[1].setAttribute("style", "border: 5px solid red; margin: 20px");
```

```html
<div>cssText yellow</div>
<div>setAttribute red</div>
```